# Teechart Gauge - draw line between 2 values

Tags: delphi, teechart, gauge

I have 2 GaugeSeries (GaugeSeries1.Value and GaugrSeries2.Value). I would like draw a line between these two values (i.e connect these 2 points with a line), but I don't know how do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Canvas property of TeeChart. As per this [example](http://www.steema.com/support/faq/NewVCL/FAQ_VCL_DRAWING.htm) which draws a rectangle, and can be modified to suit your needs -

> How can I draw extra things over a Chart ?
>
> You should use the Chart1.Canvas object ( see Delphi's TCanvas
>   documentation ).
>
> But, you should do all your drawing code at the Chart1.OnAfterDraw
>   event for the drawings to be persistent among chart repaints and to
>   get them also when printing.

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With Chart1.ChartRect do
       Canvas.Rectangle(Left,Top,Right,Bottom);
end;
```